# jQuery ScrollTo and LocalScroll make variable out of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, this, scrollto

Using [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) to navigated around a page and need to identify which link was clicked for use in a callback function. I've dug around the source of each and am unable to understand how to extract it.

What I've found for sure is that `$(this)` refers to the `body` element in its entirety. Thanks for your help!

Here's my function:

```
$('nav').localScroll({
    duration: 500,
    easing:'easeOutSine',
    axis:'xy',
    onAfter: function(){
        /* This is where I need to identify the anchor that was clicked*/
        var test = $(this);
        console.log(test);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one" class="active">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enabled `hash` option this could be useful: [JQuery > ScrollTo > highlighting the item that was scrolled to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7730400/729077).

Other solution is adding another `click` event to all links and setting variable/attribute which you could read later inside `onAfter` callback.